# How do you configure local_auth in flutter correctly if you want to secure the whole app with it (e.g. bank apps)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, fingerprint, touch-id

We have the problem that we want to protect the complete app with a fingerprint/TouchID/FaceID. I will only mention fingerprint here, which always means all biometric features of local_auth. Partly this works quite well with the function "`didChangeAppLifecycleState`", but only partly.

Since under iOS the app becomes inactive while the fingerprint is being queried, the query comes in a continuous loop when queried at "`AppLifecycleState.resumed`". Therefore we set a timestamp at "`AppLifecycleState.pause`" and query the fingerprint at resume only if x seconds have passed since the app was paused. We have now also set this to a slightly higher time, so that the lock does not go on immediately if you have to switch to the camera from the app. Of course there are more checks, but that's the basic idea right now.

1. Here is the problem that flutter takes some time to execute paused. Both iOS and Android. So if you now quickly minimize the app and open it again (because minimizing was perhaps an accident?), the fingerprint comes directly. Nothing serious, but unpleasant.
2. Our real problem, which I can't really understand, since I don't know how to debug it either. If the app hasn't been used for a long time, especially on a Monday after the weekend, then work colleagues have the problem that they can simply start the app without a fingerprint. So far only noticed under iOS, since the colleagues use all iOS, but does not exclude that it could happen under Android as well.

I just don't know how to fix it. Has anyone had any experience with this? Or **is there a very simple way to use the fingerprint in flutter** in a way that you can **open the app only with fingerprint**, maybe at a completely different place than "`didChangeAppLifecycleState`"?

Kind regards,
Jakob

Comment: Hey Jacob, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @VCezar Not really, sorry. We use now a much more complex solution with bloc pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are using lifecycle hook to prompt for biometric verification and you are having issues. The following is the solution if I understand your query right.

First instead of using lifecycle to verify the biometric check. Can you not use initialization widget which gets called every time before opening up the app. Here is an example.

```
class Initialize extends StatefulWidget {
  _InitializeState createState() => _InitializeState();
}

class _InitializeState extends State<Initialize> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initialize();
  }

  Future<void> _initialize() async {

final userDetails = await getUserSavedDetailsFromStroage();
await doAnyOtherTask();

final user = authService.checkIfPrevLoggedIn(authDetails);

if (user == null) {
  _gotoLogin();
} else {
  if (userDetails.biometricEnabled) {
    final verified = await biometricService.onBiometricVerify();
    if (!verified) {
      _gotoLogin();
      return;
    }
  }
  authService.refreshUser();
  _gotoHomePage();
}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SplashView();
  }
}
```

And your main.dart file will pretty much look like the following, I am assuming you are using Provider package for state management.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => AuthService.instance,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Initialize(),
        title: 'App Title',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct: "which gets called every time before opening up the app".  You have to handle the case of the app opening up for the first time (in which case the above is true), and the case of the app resuming after being put in the background (in which case I think it's not true).

Answer (score -1):

you can set a flag that local auth request is pending.
If you got a response then set the flag back to false with a Futuredelay of 150ms.

Request the local auth in your AppLifecycleState.resumed only if the request is not pending.